# Display values of checked checkbox in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have a form in which i want to  display the checkbox value using smarty function `html_checkboxes`, on submitting the form, i have placed all the submitted values in a variable in my php file and then displayed that variable in my template file. All values displayed except checkbox because as i know checkbox returns array, so i don't know how to access the value of that checkbox.

PHP:

```
$lang = $_POST['user_lang'][0];
$formdata = "";
if (isset($data['submit'])) {
    $formdata .= $data['user_firstname']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_lastname']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_address']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_gender']."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $lang."\n" ;
    $formdata .= $data['user_select']."\n" ;
}
$smarty->assign('data',$data);
$smarty->assign('formdata',$formdata);
```

Template:

```
<h4><{$formdata|nl2br}></h4>
```

how to print all the values of a checked checkbox?

Comment: `foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $value)`

Comment: The Smarty function [`{html_checkboxes}`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.checkboxes.tpl) is useful when you have several related checkboxes. It generates HTML that sends to the server all the checked checkboxes from the group into a single array. If you have only one checkbox (or unrelated checkboxes) its easier to write the HTML for them by hand.